# Move selected row to new sheet with button

Tags: excel, vba, rows

I have a master sheet with lots of data every day. I then have nine sheets (called `john`, `peter`, `james` etc.) I go through each row (line) and decide which work/row is for which individual then cut the selected row (example row 5) than go into that persons sheet (example `james`) than select the next free row and paste. Than return to the master sheet delete the empty row (example row 5) and repeat for the next person till the master sheet is empty.

What I'm trying to do is create buttons at the top of the sheet to link to macros/VBA with that person's name on and when going through the master sheet (Sheet 1 same workbook) want to select a row then press the button and that selected row be moved to that person's sheet in the next free row and deleting the original row.

Comment: Have you tried any Excel VBA tutorials to start learning to do this type of coding?

Comment: Thanks Barett, i have done several tutorials which show how to move and copy between sheets but not to the level i'm trying , hence the question for help ...

Answer (score 1):

Copy once for each sheet & rename sht2 as needed. Assign each copy to a button.

```
Sub move_row()

'Declare variables
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim sht3 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

'Set variables
    Set sht1 = Sheets("Master")
    Set sht2 = Sheets("John")

'Select Entire Row
    Selection.EntireRow.Select

'Move row to destination sheet & Delete source row
    lastRow = sht2.Range("A" & sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With Selection
        .Copy Destination:=sht2.Range("A" & lastRow + 1)
        .EntireRow.Delete
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow , thanks a million i will be trying this first thing in the morning and let you know :) Awesome !